# Why can't I display Font-Awesome with Angular5

Tags: css, fonts, angular5

I have an angular 5 app which uses bootstrap (working fine) and font-awesome (5, free).

Chrome shows me this error:

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:5020/fa-solid-900.10c304f14cd2f6b6bed2.eot?#iefix)%20format(%22embedded-opentype%22),url(../webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2)%20format(%22woff2%22),url(../webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff)%20format(%22woff%22),url(../webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf)%20format(%22truetype%22),url(../webfonts/fa-solid-900.svg#fontawesome)%20format(%22svg%22:5020/#/flightBoard:1 
OTS parsing error: invalid version tag
```

I think it is because of th #/flightboard:1 which is added at the end?

But why does angular add this at the end of my fonts and how do I prevent this?

Comment: Please provide your code to import fontawesome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem with your angular CLI. 
See: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9726, 
Ran into this problem myself recently.
Upgrade your Angular CLI to v1.7.3 and this should fix your problem.